# ApplicationContext with global variable lost after back pressed

Tags: java, android, android-context

I have a little problem with my global variable declared in a global class called `Controller` which extend from application.

When I start Activity A I have an arraylist with 0 items in `Controller`( it's a cart), I go on activity B, on click, I add an item to "Controller", I go back (with back button) on activity A and I get an arraylist still at 0 items what's wrong ?

My controller class :

```
public class Controller extends Application {

    public static final int SIGNUP_REQUEST = 98;  // The request code
    public static final int SIGNIN_REQUEST = 99;
    private User mUser;// Instance de l'utilisateur connecté
    private Cart mCart = new Cart(); // Panier
    private Tracker mTracker; // Analytics
    private Session mSession;
    private SessionModule mSessionModule;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
        mSessionModule = new SessionModule(base);
        mSession = mSessionModule.getSession();
    }

    public Cart getCart() {

        return mCart;
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        return mSession;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return mUser;
    }

    public void setUser(User mUser) {
        this.mUser = mUser;
    }
}
```

My Cart Class :

```
public class Cart {
    private ArrayList<Item> items i= new ArrayList<Item>();
    private Store mStore;

    public Item getItem(int pPosition) {

        return items.get(pPosition);
    }

    public void addItem(Item item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    public void removeItem(int pPosition) {
        items.remove(pPosition);
    }

    public void clear() {
        items.clear();
    }

    public int size() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public ArrayList<Item> getItems() {

        return items;

    }
}
```

A BaseActivity which get the instance of controller in onCreate() :

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Session mSession;
    public Controller mController;

    public static final int SIGNUP_REQUEST = 98;  // The request code
    public static final int SIGNIN_REQUEST = 99;

    public static final int LOGIN_REQUEST = 1;  // The request code
    public static final int REGISTER_REQUEST = 2;  // The request code

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mController=(Controller)getApplicationContext();

        mSession=mController.getSession();

    }
```

On my `MainActivity extends BaseActivity (Activity A)` called in `onResume()`, I have an method which refresh UI badges :

```
 public void checkCartItems(){
        if(itemCart!=null){
            LayerDrawable iconCart = (LayerDrawable) itemCart.getIcon();
            int nb_items=mController.getCart().size();
            Tools.setBadgeCount(this, iconCart,String.valueOf(nb_items));
        }

    }
```

On Activity B extends BaseActivity on OnClick() I call a simple add :

```
mController.getCart().addItem(mItem);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `Application` class `Singleton`. Like this:

```
public class Controller extends Application {

    public static final int SIGNUP_REQUEST = 98;  // The request code
    public static final int SIGNIN_REQUEST = 99;
    private User mUser;// Instance de l'utilisateur connecté
    private Cart mCart = new Cart(); // Panier
    private Tracker mTracker; // Analytics
    private Session mSession;
    private SessionModule mSessionModule;
    private static Controller _mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        _mInstance = this;

    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
        mSessionModule = new SessionModule(base);
        mSession = mSessionModule.getSession();
    }

    public static synchronized Controller getInstance() {
        return _mInstance;
    }

    public Cart getCart() {

        return mCart;
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        return mSession;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return mUser;
    }

    public void setUser(User mUser) {
        this.mUser = mUser;
    }
}
```

Then while using `Application` class, use `Controller.getInstance().getCart().addItem(mItem);`

Comment: Tried but the problem is still there : Activity A 0 items, Activity B 1 items Activity C 1 items (back button to Activity A) 0 items

Comment: Is there anywhere, where you trying to flush the data from any of the `Activity`? If yes, is it getting called in way back to `Activity A`?

Comment: It's OK !!! :) i have forget to modifiy one other activity ! Thank you i have learn a new thing today ^^

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the static pattern for this kind of operations, so that the Cart object is the same across the entire lifecycle of the application.

Here's the solution for the Controller :

Step 1 : Inside the controller class, set the Cart to be static (modify the getter of the Cart to be static as well)

```
private static Cart mCart;
```

Step 2 : Initialize the instance in the onCreate of the Controller

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mCart = new Cart();
}
```

How to use : get the cart from anywhere using

```
Controller.getCart();
```